# How to tell if the java logging sockethandler is still running?

Tags: java, sockets, java.util.logging

I have an app that creates a socket handler to my log server (on a different device) and uses it. This works fine.

If the log sever is terminated and restarted the app does not know this. The app should remove the old socket handler and add a new one.

How can I tell if the java logging sockethandler is still running?

Edit: I came up with the code below which seems to work:

```
    public static class MySocketHandler extends SocketHandler {
        public MySocketHandler(String host,int port, Logger logger) throws IOException {
            super(host,port);
            this.logger=logger;
            setErrorManager(new ErrorManager() {
                @Override public synchronized void error(String msg,Exception ex,int code) {
                    super.error(msg,ex,code);
                    System.out.println("error: "+msg+", "+ex+", "+code);
                    removeHandler();
                    failed=true;
                }
            });
        }
        void removeHandler() {
            logger.removeHandler(MySocketHandler.this);
            System.out.println("removed my socket handler");
        }
        final Logger logger;
        Boolean failed=false;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a proxy handler to wrap the [SocketHandler](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/logging/SocketHandler.html)
and install a custom [`java.util.logging.ErrorManager`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/logging/ErrorManager.html) (as an inner class) to listen for exceptions and reconnect the internal handler on error.

Here is some example code for you to improve and make sure you unit test it before you use it:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.ArrayDeque;
import java.util.logging.ErrorManager;
import java.util.logging.Filter;
import java.util.logging.Formatter;
import java.util.logging.Handler;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.LogRecord;
import java.util.logging.SocketHandler;

public class ReconnectingSocketHandler extends Handler {

    private SocketHandler target;
    private boolean active;
    private final Watcher listener = new Watcher();
    private final ArrayDeque<LogRecord> pending = new ArrayDeque<>(1);

    public ReconnectingSocketHandler() {
        //@todo Read properties from LogManager.
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void publish(LogRecord record) {
        if (!active) {  //Prevent reentrance.
            active = true;
            try {
                if (record != null && isLoggable(record)) {
                    pending.add(record);
                }

                //Store only the last few records only on error.
                if (pending.size() > 1000) {
                    pending.pollFirst();
                }

                //While we have retries and records.
                for (int r = 0; r < 2 && !pending.isEmpty(); ++r) {
                    if (target == null) {
                        //@todo implement time based backoff.
                        target = new SocketHandler();
                        target.setLevel(super.getLevel());
                        target.setEncoding(super.getEncoding());
                        target.setFilter(super.getFilter());
                        target.setFormatter(super.getFormatter());
                        target.setErrorManager(listener);
                    }

                    //Write the queue to the socket handler.
                    for (LogRecord lr; (lr = pending.poll()) != null;) {
                        target.publish(lr);
                        //On error, close and retry.
                        if (listener.last != null) {
                            pending.addFirst(lr);
                            reportError(null, listener.last,
                                    ErrorManager.WRITE_FAILURE);
                            listener.last = null;
                            target.close();
                            target = null;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (IOException ioe) {
                target = null; //Try again later.
                reportError(null, ioe, ErrorManager.WRITE_FAILURE);
            } finally {
                active = false;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void flush() {
        publish((LogRecord) null);
        if (target != null) {
            target.flush();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void close() {
        super.setLevel(Level.OFF);
        flush();
        if (target != null) {
            target.close();
            target = null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void setLevel(Level newLevel) {
        super.setLevel(newLevel);
        if (target != null) {
            target.setLevel(newLevel);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void setFilter(Filter newFilter) {
        super.setFilter(newFilter);
        if (target != null) {
            target.setFilter(newFilter);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void setEncoding(String encoding) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        super.setEncoding(encoding);
        if (target != null) {
            target.setEncoding(encoding);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void setFormatter(Formatter newFormatter) {
        super.setFormatter(newFormatter);
        if (target != null) {
            target.setFormatter(newFormatter);
        }
    }

    private class Watcher extends ErrorManager {

        Exception last;

        Watcher() {
        }

        @Override
        public void error(String msg, Exception ex, int code) {
            last = ex;
        }
    }
}
```

This code will publish to the socket handler in the normal path.  On exception, it will close and recreate the socket handler.  If that fails, this code will store the current record up to the last 1000 records in a queue for delayed publishing.

Removing and adding the socket handler to the logger tree is a racy operation and could result losing log records or a flurry of reconnects.  The proxy handler will allow you to properly control the number of reconnects and it allows you to re-publish errors that would otherwise be lost.

> How can I tell if the java logging sockethandler is still running?

You can try to periodically call [`flush`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/logging/Handler.html#flush--) to detect a closed socket but that is overkill. If the observer device is down and no errors occur in the source application it doesn't really matter if the socket is up or not. Reacting at the time of failure is probably all you need to do.

Comment: looks like you are trying to save as many messages as possible. in my case, these are a bunch of dedicated tablets in the field logging to a file adapter on each device. plugging in a cable is not always feasible since the tablet may be mounted in a box. sometimes a laptop may appear on the wifi network to capture the logs. so i wanted the socket handlers to quit and restart gracefully when power cycles and other things go wrong.

Comment: @RayTayek The example code is only storing records when the connection is broken.  Every publish will attempt to reconnect the socket handler and publish any backlog of records.

Comment: oh, i missed that. my app will usually run for long periods of time with no log server around. i have code that periodically tries to establish a new socket handler.